# Why are my CSS snap points not taking effect?

Tags: css

[CSS Snap Points](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap) are supported by recent versions of both Chrome and Safari, but for some reason [my implementation](https://codepen.io/segdeha/pen/XyoXvz?editors=0100) (← CodePen link so you can try it out) is not snapping.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious. Any help is appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div id="treats"><a class="treat"><span></span></a><a class="treat"><span></span></a><a class="treat"><span></span></a><a class="treat"><span></span></a><a class="treat"><span></span></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font: 16px/1.5 Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#treats {
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    width: 500vw;
}

.treat {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0 0.25em 0.25em;
    transition: all 0.25s;
    width: 100vw;
}
    .treat:active {
        text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0 0.1em 0.1em;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0.025em, 0);
    }
    .treat span {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 33vh;
    }

.treat:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #ffabab;
}
.treat:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #ffdaab;
}
.treat:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #ddffab;
}
.treat:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #abe4ff;
}
.treat:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: #d9abff;
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/sahilweb6/pen/MzZyvO

Comment: Thanks, @SahilDhir. I'd love to know *why* that works. Are you willing to write a more complete answer? Your CodePen mixes CSS properties that Firefox and Safari alternately complain are not valid. Is it the use of `flex` that makes it work? I haven't seen that documented anywhere, but it's another difference between yours and mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to studying the comment by @SahilDhir, I was able to get this working. My solution is a little different from his, so I'm posting it below. Specifically, I only need to support iOS, so I took out some of the cross-browser CSS. I also used `grid` instead of `flex` to set up my boxes.

```
body {
    font: 16px/1.5 Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100vw;
}

#treats {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100vw 100vw 100vw 100vw 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    width: 100vw;
}

.treat {
    font-size: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0 0.25em 0.25em;
    transition: all 0.25s;
    width: 100vw;
}
    .treat:active {
        text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0 0.1em 0.1em;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0.025em, 0);
    }
    .treat span {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 33vh;
    }

.treat:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #ffabab;
}
.treat:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #ffdaab;
}
.treat:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #ddffab;
}
.treat:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #abe4ff;
}
.treat:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: #d9abff;
}
```

Here's an [updated CodePen showing it in action](https://codepen.io/segdeha/pen/EOGrjo?editors=1100).